# Build and run your image in docker - network problem

Tags: docker, dockerfile, npm-install

I am on Ubuntu 16.04

I am completely new to docker and I am trying to follow this tutorial:
https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/

When I arrive at giving the command: 
`docker build --tag bulletinboard:1.0 .`

I get stuck at:

```
Step 4/7 : RUN npm install
 ---> Running in c39c53244bbc
```

I tried also to put a `--verbose` after the `npm install` command and this is what I get in addition to getting stuck:

```
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm verb cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'install', '--verbose' ]
npm info using npm@6.14.4
npm info using node@v12.16.2
npm verb npm-session 6c1c828b01ec87d3
npm info lifecycle vue-event-bulletin@1.0.0~preinstall: vue-event-bulletin@1.0.0
npm timing stage:loadCurrentTree Completed in 19ms
npm timing stage:loadIdealTree:cloneCurrentTree Completed in 0ms
npm timing stage:loadIdealTree:loadShrinkwrap Completed in 3ms
npm timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 1ms
npm timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 320451ms
npm verb type request-timeout
npm verb stack FetchError: network timeout at: https://registry.npmjs.org/bootstrap
npm verb stack     at Timeout._onTimeout (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-fetch-npm/src/index.js:61:18)
npm verb stack     at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:549:17)
npm verb stack     at processTimers (internal/timers.js:492:7)
npm verb cwd /usr/src/app
npm verb Linux 4.15.0-96-generic
npm verb argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "--verbose"
npm verb node v12.16.2
npm verb npm  v6.14.4
npm ERR! network timeout at: https://registry.npmjs.org/bootstrap
npm verb exit [ 1, true ]
```

It seems to be a network issue (i.e. my docker container is not able to connect to the internet). I tried a lot of solutions from the internet but it seems that nothing worked for me. It is really frustrating because is the 2nd tutorial of the docker guide.

Could you please help me?

Comment: What is your host operating system? Do you have a local firewall running (or possibly an external one) that might be blocking those requests? Can you connect to https://registry.npmjs.org/bootstrap from the host?

Comment: I edited my question: I am on Ubuntu 16.04. I will try tomorrow to ping the registry.npmjs.org when I have access again to the machine

Comment: instead of `ping` try `curl 'https://registry.npmjs.org/bootstrap'`instead. If a firewall is blocking traffic (which seems pretty unlikely but stranger things have happened) it might have different rules for TCP versus ICMP.

Comment: Sometimes when I get random hangs like this, disabling IPv6 helps (sad, I know).

Comment: Thanks to all of you for your help. The problem disappeared when I just restarted my machine this morning. I don't know what was the specific problem

Answer (score 2):

It's a simple firewalld issue.

run

```
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=trusted --add-interface=docker0
```

and restart your firewalld,

```
sudo systemctl restart firewalld
```

Comment: Thanks for this. After thinking it was some sort of npm (in docker builder) issue, this resolved the problem for me on my CentOS 8 server.